# Why did Krishna try to negotiate with the Kauravas if the Pandavas had sworn revenge on them?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas

In the aftermath of Draupadi's disrobing (*vastraharan*), Bhima takes an oath:

> "Ye lords of earth, if having spoken these words I do not accomplish them hereafter, let me not obtain the region of my deceased ancestors. Tearing open in battle, by sheer force, the breast of this wretch, this wicked-minded scoundrel of the Bharata race, if I do not drink his life-blood, let me not obtain the region of my ancestors." ([Source](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02067.htm))

Then, according to [this article](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02067.htm), it seems that all the other Pandava brothers agree, and on their own declarations:

> At the end of the second Dice game, Bhima repeats his vows before the whole assembly. He says that he will pierce Dussasana’s chest and drink his blood. He will break Duryodhana’s thighs and hit his head when he prostrates on the ground.
>
> Bhima insists that earth should drink the blood of Duryodhana, Dussasana, Karna and Shakuni.
>
> Arjun approves of his words and says that he will do what Bhima had directed him to do after thirteen years. He will kill Karna and his followers and slay all those who stand against him in battlefield.
>
> Sahadeva admits that he will obey Bhima’s word and kill Shakuni along with all his people. Nakula vows the death of Dhritarashtra’s sons in battlefield which incidentally is accomplished by Bhima alone.

(There is also the story of Draupadi vowing to wash her hair in Bhima’s blood. This was not in any of the original versions, but instead seems to have arisen from the Venisamhara. ([Source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41694945?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) Nevertheless, it still supports the idea that the Pandavas wanted revenge)

Clearly, tensions are running high. The Pandavas are angry; they have sworn vengeance, to be served after their exile. It seems to me that having taken these vows, the war is both inevitable and now required.

However, after the Pandavas have finished the thirteen years, Krishna went to Hastinapura to negotiate with the Kauravas in order to avert the war. He asked for five villages, one for each Pandava brother, but Duryodhana famously said that he would not part with even a single "needlepoint of land." It was only *after* the Kauravas denied his request that war was actually declared.

My question is: Why did Krishna try to prevent the war if all of the brothers had made oaths of vengeance? How could they have fulfilled those vows if there was no war?